The AI in an office building tries to kill an employee
So, I watched this live-action movie sometime around September 1995. Movie was shown on the local channel in my country. It was definitely an American movie, probably made in the 80's or nearly 90's. This guess is solely based on the fact that it was a colour movie.
The story is about a Caucasian man who starts work at this new company of his. The secretary/receptionist(female) takes him to his work desk and along the way reminds him to take care of his computer. I think she might have said something about the computer has feelings or something. He ignores this thinking it's what they say to all their employees. In one scene, I think he spilled coffee over the keyboard.
After a couple of incidents him mistreating the computer, it was implied that the computer wants to take revenge. Well, in this particular office, every employer is given an access card. This is how the AI was able to track the hero and tried to kill him on 2 separate occasions :

In the elevator - however the hero's colleague(male, Caucasian) borrowed the access card and he was killed instead, squashed when the doors was closing I think.
In the office sauna - another colleague of the hero's, this time an african american man borrowed his access card to use the office's sauna or jacuzzi(not too sure). the AI then increased the temperature until he was dehydrated or burnt to death.

In the end, it was a full on battle between the hero and the AI. This happened in the office building after working hours as the AI's only intention is to kill the hero. Somehow though, the heroin(female, Caucasian) was also in the building so the both of them somehow defeated the AI. I also do remember a lot of explosion and fire and possibly the firetruck came in the end after they escaped the building. 
So, I hope these info are enough. Will definitely keep on updating if anything comes into mind. Thanks in advance !!

You're looking for The Tower from 1993 with Paul Reiser.

Before Tony can get to work on the first day of his new job, he manages to lock himself out of his appartment. To get back in he uses the his new security pass, which resembles a credit card. The card becomes damaged when it is used to open his front door, and then causes mayhem at work when the main computer fails to identify Tony as the new employee. The high-tech building is run by computer, which interprets its programming as meaning; "destroy all threats". The BUILDING is out to get Tony.

IIRC, everything you mentioned is there. Here's a review with some clips from the film:




I might have been off with some of the details I provided, but that was definitely the movie I've been looking for. Thanks a bunch Walt !!

I think you were right on the money with most of them. The one thing you didn't mention is ironically the one I remember most vividly: The pair of them almost freezing to death while trying to shut down the computer near the end. Glad you found it. :)

I definitely did not remember that part at all. Was surprised myself when I went through the video on Youtube and saw that. Lots of the scene were quite different than how I remembered though.
